# adding ipset tag

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, retag-request

I have a question about my Server Fault post: [replacing a runtime instance of ipset](https://serverfault.com/questions/842585/replacing-a-runtime-instance-of-ipset)

I'd like to add [ipset](https://serverfault.com/questions/tagged/ipset) tag to my question. There are actually quite a few questions on serverfault that cover ipset, so the tag is justified and is more specific as iptables alone is not sufficient and too general anymore. Can someone on meta to add the ipset tag?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I've just created the tag [ipset](https://serverfault.com/questions/tagged/ipset).